# ASP.NET MVC route only works on server but not on local development machine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

When I try to access the `Index` view of my controller, I get an HTTP 404 error.

But if I deploy the app on the server, everything works fine. Even if I access my action by typing in the URL `User/Index`.

The problem is it can't find the `Index` action on its on.

I don't have this problem with other controllers. For example I can input: `/Weather`, `/Forms` just fine, and it goes directly into the `Index` action methods of those controllers.

This is my `UserController` and its `Index` action method:

```
public class UserController : SerializeController
{
    private readonly IUsers Users;

    public UserController(IUsers users)
    {
        Users = users;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    ......
}
```

and my `RouteConfig.cs` :

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

It's weird - why is this only happening on the `Index` action of that one controller - and not others?

I'm also using Autofac dependency injection and registering my interface like this :

```
Container.RegisterType<Users>().As<IUsers>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

For Calling this controller , Ive just using simple browser call e.g.:

http://localhost:2569/User , and it shows :

[image]

And Also Chrome network tab result :

[image]

But if i publish it into IIS and call  example.org/User  , the action opens without any problem.

Comment: Pls show us the code you are using to call user/index action

Comment: @serge just a simple get or url call from browser. https://www.example.org/User